# could not install tigramite package

Tags: python, anaconda

I get the following error when trying to install the `tigramite` package:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\IC3\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\IC3\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v7nlp1rq\\tigramite_ebe1ab9fa0f04c4ea4e283de07b9517b\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\IC3\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v7nlp1rq\\tigramite_ebe1ab9fa0f04c4ea4e283de07b9517b\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\IC3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q5e2snyq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\IC3\anaconda3\Include\tigramite'
```

This is on Windows in an Anaconda Python distribution.

What is causing this and how can I get it to install?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) also check out the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.

Comment: Please include the command you used to attempt the installation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.